# Angular $broadcast only updating after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, broadcast, rootscope

Hi I have a problem in Angular where `$scope.$broadcast` is only updating a listening value once the page has been refreshed once:

One controller:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myVar', myValue);
```

Listener:

```
$scope.$on('myVar', function(event, myValue) {
    console.log(myValue);
    $scope.myValue= myValue;
});
```

It works if I refresh the page once, but on initial load the listener is not working?
Any ideas?

Comment: If you put the `$on` in the same file as the `$broadcast` do you see the same behaviour?  Is the controller on the page before a refresh?

Comment: It works if I put the listener in the same file.

Comment: what if you try ``$rootScope.$on('myVar', `` ?

Comment: That didn't work either?

Comment: If it works in the same file, check out the order in which the files are loaded (order in the `index.html`).  Since, the browser caches the files, the order wouldn't matter after a refresh.

Comment: I have solved the problem, using `$window.location.reload();` it appeared that I needed to reload the controller to re-initiate the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, using `$window.location.reload();` it appeared that I needed to reload the controller to re-initiate the listener.